# nodejs filter array of object by key

Tags: node.js, routes, underscore.js

I am new to nodeJS, As i am working with routes and storing the value of firstRoute response in an array and filtering the array values in second Route. as below

```
var _ = require('underscore');
var apiInfo = require('../../utils/email_api');
//apiInfo is utility 

app.get('/api/fleets', function(req, res, next) {
    var fileToRead = pathReader.filePath() + 'fleets.json';
    fs.readFile(fileToRead, 'utf8', function(err, data) {
        if (err) throw err;
         // here I am setting the apiInfo.fleets which has data
        apiInfo.fleets = data;
        res.send(data);
    });
});
```

and in the second URL

```
app.get('/api/fleet/:fleet_uuid/vehicles', function(req, res, next) {
    var fleets = apiInfo.fleets;
    //now fleets contains the assigned value in first api call
    //If i pass fleets = [](static array) i can able to filter.
    var fleet_uuid = req.params.fleet_uuid
    ,   fleetFound = _.find(fleets, function(fleet){ return fleet.id === req.params.fleet_uuid; });
    //The fleet Found is always printing undefined(how can i filter the fleet Found)
    console.log(fleetFound);
});
```

if i pass fleets = staticArray i can able to filter the value, Butfor dynamic array assigned in first api call, I can able to print(print correct array values, but not able to filter)

Comment: What type is the `id` in the `fleets` object?

Answer (score 0):

Your issue is you are reading in the file as a string instead of storing it as a proper object

what you need to do is `JSON.parse` the data from the `fs.readFile`.

so when you are using `_.find`, you are using each character in the string.

for example reading in a file:

```
{
  "data": [1,2,3,4,5]
}
```

will be stored as :

```
 { fleets: '{\r\n  "data": [1,2,3,4,5]\r\n}\r\n' }
```

```js
 app.get('/api/fleets', function(req, res, next) {
   var fileToRead = pathReader.filePath() + 'fleets.json';
   fs.readFile(fileToRead, 'utf8', function(err, data) {
     if (err) throw err;
     
     apiInfo.fleets = JSON.parse(data); // parse the data
     res.send(data);
   });
 });
```